# iPhone music is skipping

Tags: itunes, iphone, music, ios

Some of the music on my iPhone 4G 32Gig started skipping intermittently when I play it on the phone. These are mp3 files synch'd to the iPhone through iTunes from my Windows 7 laptop.

I have filled it to 28G.

The same song played back again at a later time does not skip but another one might.

What is going on here?

What do I do about this?

Comment: Is this a problem when playing music from your computer?

Comment: @Nathan this happens when I am playing it on my iPhone

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the music stutters, but keeps playing on the same song? Can you tell me if your phone is jailbroken?

Comment: @IntuitionHQ It sounds like when a CD skips. My phone is not jailbroken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely sounds like its fragmentation-related.

I found a few sources, take with a grain-of-salt but it seems to back up the hypothesis.

- http://sites.google.com/site/tony72/ppc_frag
- http://www.lagom.nl/misc/flash_fragmentation.html
- https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74472-6_13
- http://www.diskeeper.com/blog/post/2007/06/22/The-Impact-of-Fragmentation-on-Flash-Drives-%28iPods-Jump-Drives-etc%29.aspx

*My earlier post:*

Edit: Thank you for the info.

<s>Some additional info could help with this:</s>

- iPhone release (orig, 3g, 3gs etc...)
- codec of audio: (mp3? apple lossless?
  aiff?...)

Without the additional info, my first hypothesis would be that its a memory issue. You might try killing some other apps (yes, I know they shouldn't be running, but there may be some related processing happening in the background.)

To take it to another extreme for testing purposes, do you have video clips you could try? If so, test them out and come back if there's any useful information gathered.

One last thing, I doubt its related but, how full is the storage on the iPhone?

Comment: @mummey question edited to add info

Comment: Playing video does not skip. The same song again has not skipped either.

Comment: Interesting, about how far (in seconds) does it get before it starts skipping?

Comment: Both times it happened, it was toward the end of the song. Then I replayed the song.. no skipping!

Comment: The song length long or short? (a thought that maybe its somehow being played back faster than it can be read into memory.)

Comment: One last suggestion: Maybe somehow the song is fragmented in flash memory (I don't think that should be an issue though). In any case, maybe try backing up your current contents on the iPhone, Restoring the iPhone using an image of the current iOS version, then applying the backup to get your data back on it.  Hopefully that should be enough to get it to behave correctly.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I did remove all songs from my iPhone recently because I needed the space for video recordings. I just put them all back in. This started happening after the reload.

Comment: Revised answer above. Hope this solves it!